# What are the number of solutions of $|\sqrt{2\sin^4 x+18\cos^2 x}-\sqrt{2\cos^4 x+18\sin^2 x}|=1?$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing, absolute-value, substitution

> The number of $x\in [0,2\pi]$ for which
>
> $\bigg|\sqrt{2\sin^4 x+18\cos^2 x}-\sqrt{2\cos^4 x+18\sin^2 x}\bigg|=1$ is

What I did try was:

Let $$f(x)=\bigg|\sqrt{2\sin^4 x+18\cos^2 x}-\sqrt{2\cos^4 x+18\sin^2 x}\bigg|$$

then $$f\bigg(\frac{\pi}{2}+x\bigg)=\bigg|\sqrt{2\sin^4 x+18\cos^2 x}-\sqrt{2\cos^4 x+18\sin^2 x}\bigg|$$

So, $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2}$ is a time period of that function.

How do I solve this? Pls, I need help.

Comment: It is also even function, so you can restrict study on $[0,\frac{\pi}4]$. If you could prove it is decreasing on that interval, you can show it has only $1$ solution.

Comment: You could also consider $f(x)=\frac{16\cos(2x)}{\bar f(x)}$ where $\bar f$ is the conjugated (i.e. same than $f$ but with a $+$ sign).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\sin^2x\cos^2x=t$.

Thus, we have
$$2(\sin^4x+\cos^4x)+18(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)-4\sqrt{(\sin^4x+9\cos^2x)(\cos^4x+9\sin^2x)}=1$$ or
$$2-4t+18-1=4\sqrt{t^2+9(1-3t)+81t}$$ or
$$19-4t=4\sqrt{t^2+54t+9}$$ or
$$t=\frac{217}{1016}$$
or $$\sin^22x=\frac{217}{254}$$ or
$$1-\cos4x=\frac{217}{127}$$ or
$$\cos4x=-\frac{90}{127}.$$
Can you end it now?

I got $8$ roots.

Indeed, $$4x=\pm\left(\pi-\arccos\frac{90}{127}\right)+2\pi k,$$ where $k\in\mathbb Z$ or
$$x=\pm\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{4}\arccos\frac{90}{127}\right)+\frac{\pi k}{2}$$ and since $0\leq x\leq2\pi,$ we obtain:
$$0\leq\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{4}\arccos\frac{90}{127}\right)+\frac{\pi k}{2}\leq2\pi,$$ which gives 
$$-0.375...-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\pi}\arccos\frac{90}{127}\leq k\leq \frac{7}{2}+\frac{1}{2\pi}\arccos\frac{90}{127}=3.624...,$$ for which $k\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ are valid or 
$$0\leq-\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{4}\arccos\frac{90}{127}\right)+\frac{\pi k}{2}\leq2\pi,$$ which gives 
$$0.375...=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2\pi}\arccos\frac{90}{127}\leq k\leq \frac{9}{2}-\frac{1}{2\pi}\arccos\frac{90}{127}=4.375...,$$ for which $k\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ are valid and we obtain $8$ roots only:
$$x_1=\frac{1}{4}\left(\pi+\arccos\frac{90}{127}\right),$$
$$x_2=\frac{1}{4}\left(3\pi+\arccos\frac{90}{127}\right),$$
$$x_3=\frac{1}{4}\left(5\pi+\arccos\frac{90}{127}\right),$$
$$x_4=\frac{1}{4}\left(7\pi+\arccos\frac{90}{127}\right),$$
$$x_5=\frac{1}{4}\left(\pi-\arccos\frac{90}{127}\right),$$
$$x_6=\frac{1}{4}\left(3\pi-\arccos\frac{90}{127}\right),$$
$$x_7=\frac{1}{4}\left(5\pi-\arccos\frac{90}{127}\right)$$ and
$$x_8=\frac{1}{4}\left(7\pi-\arccos\frac{90}{127}\right).$$

Comment: I make the numerator of $t$ to be 217

Comment: Yes, you are right. My mistake. But the answer is the same. I'll fix it later because I am driving now. Thank you!

Comment: @sani I added something. See now.

Comment: @sani I made some work for you. Say please something: It's clear now, it's not clear...

Comment: Thank You so much... I already understood the solution before you edited.. That's why I deleted my comment..@MichaelRozenberg

Comment: But I am now having another problem.. It would be great if you kindly help me... I can not understand how you supposed that all the eight roots of the  equation $$\cos4x=-\frac{90}{127}.$$ are also roots of the main equation..Basically I am doubting if there is any root which satisfies $$\cos4x=-\frac{90}{127}.$$ and does not satisfy the main equation.@MichaelRozenberg

Comment: Like if $x =2$ and we square both sides we get $x ^2 =2^2$..and then we will get two solutions of $x$..$-2$ is obviously an extraneous root..I am doubting if something like this happens in your solution..@MichaelRozenberg

Comment: @sani I added something. I hope now it's clear.

Comment: Still I can not understand how you are supposing that all root of the equation  $$\sin^22x=\frac{217}{254}$$ will satisfy the main equation.@MichaelRozenberg

Comment: @sani I used $\sin^22x=\frac{1-\cos4x}{2}.$ See please better my post.

Comment: No no that is okay..But my question is how solution you are getting by squaring both sides of the equation satisfying the primary equation?@MichaelRozenberg

Comment: @sani If your mean the first step, because $|a|=1\Leftrightarrow a^2=1.$ Maybe your question about third step? If so, because $19-4t>0.$

Comment: Probably you are not getting my doubt..If $x =2$ $  \Rightarrow x^2 = 4$$ x = \pm 2$. Now can we tell that  $x =-2$ is the root of the equation  $x =2$ ?@MichaelRozenberg

Comment: This is my question.You have also squared both sides of the equation and then solve the new equation.I am asking how you are claiming they will satisfy the primary equation?

Comment: See my previous comment. I explained it.

Comment: I am really not being able to find where is the explanation?@MichaelRozenberg

Comment: It would be very helpful , if you kindly mention where you have explained.@MichaelRozenberg

Comment: Can you say, which line in my solution is not clear? I wrote: $|a|=1\Leftrightarrow a^2=1$ are you agree?